# Correct way to typeset a bold and dotted math symbol?

Tags: math-mode, typography

OK, I've seen related questions which indicate that you only bold the main symbol and not subscripts, and a few other almost related questions. But what about when you are using a bold math symbol dotted?

That is, I have a letter which represents a vector. We've been writing vectors as bold letters, i.e `\mathbf{u}`.

We represent the first time derivative of this symbol by putting a dot on it. Should I bold the dot or not? That is choice:

1. `\mathbf{\dot{u}}`, or
2. `\dot{\mathbf{u}}`

*Edit*: All things equal, I prefer the way choice 2 looks.

Comment: In a general setting, applying some formatting to a symbol (letter, or otherwise) changes its meaning. In a similar way that `U` is different from `\mathcal{U}`, say. So, I would keep the operator symbol (`\dot` in this case) the same and therefore *not* **bold**.

Comment: I'd keep option 2.  You are differentiating the vector, and thus there is no reason why the dot should be inside the "bolding" command.

Comment: *Ah the author forgot `\dot` inside the `\mathbf`...* would be my reaction to that.

Comment: @percusse huh? reaction to what?

Comment: Reading a bold dot.

Answer (score 1):

No, you should not print the dot bold. It `\dot` means a derivative, why should one assume that it's bold version have  the same meaning?

Comment: I think you misinterpret what the OP was asking.  The bold part of the symbol means it's a vector.  What he is asking is whether the dot (meaning the first derivative) should also be bold as well.

Comment: @MarioS.E. It is difficult to give a meaning of (skalar) derivative of a vector, indeed. But if `\matxbf{f}=(x^2,0,1)` one can interprete its vector derivative as the scalar one.

Comment: @e-birk Thank your for your comment. My answer is earlier than OP's edit. (Corrected, as you had suggested).